# What is the life span of a game room in Google Play Game Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

When using the Google Play Services Android API for creating a Multiplayer game Room
using com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient.createRoom(RoomConfig)

Would it be adequate to implement a Gifts subsystem using a Room?

I'll explain -

I want to send a virtual gift to my friend whom I invited to a game Room.
That friend may see the message some time in the future,
it can be right away or can be next week.

Is the life span of a Room is enough for such purpose or is the Room disposed when the host leaves
it?

Thanks, Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the room is disposed when all joined players leave it.

Second, the invitations do sometimes appear even after the inviter has abandoned the room process, but they aren't "supposed" to be there.   (some of the recent updates to GPGS have made it a lot better than a few months ago, but still occur sporadically)

So, if you are planning on gifting via the room process, there is no guarantee that just because someone sees an invitation, that there will be a room to link into for that invitee.